# Regular Expression to search all occurrence of a string

Tags: regex

How do I use regular expression to extract all occurrence of a string from a text?

My case is:

Input Text: `i:0#.f|ldapmember|tom;i:0#.f|ldaprole|peter;i:0#.f|ldapmember|mary;`

Extract all occurrence `i:0#.f|ldapmember|` with continuing characters until `;`

Search result would be: `i:0#.f|ldapmember|tom;i:0#.f|ldapmember|mary;`

Comment: (I hate that this is customary to ask...) What language? What have you tried?

Comment: To answer your question literally: Normally languages provide methods to extract substrings. E.g. in JS: `var matches = str.matches(pattern);`.

Comment: Thanks for all your guys help. Sorry not to mention the langauge. I do think the language should be .NET as I am using regular expression under "Nintex Workflow" which is built on SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, the capture of the LDAP member name is in group 1:

```
i:0\#\.f\|ldapmember\|([^;]*);
```

Comment: you're missing the global flag, as they asked for *all* occurrences, but once that is applied this works.

Comment: @lain: The "global" flag is implementation-specific; since no language has been specified it is unclear whether this would be necessary/supported/required or not. For instance, when using this regex in Java or .NET, there's no need for that flag.

Comment: That's fair enough, but I think it's still worth mentioning it as most other regex flavours would require it (or the application of a similar method, such as `scan` in Ruby).

Comment: Thanks for all your guys help. Sorry not to mention the langauge. I do think the language should be .NET as I am using regular expression under "Nintex Workflow" which is built on SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my $str = 'i:0#.f|ldapmember|tom;i:0#.f|ldaprole|peter;i:0#.f|ldapmember|mary;';
my @occ = $str =~ /(i:0#\.f\|ldapmember\|[^;]+)/g;
say join('',@occ);
```

**output:**

```
i:0#.f|ldapmember|tomi:0#.f|ldapmember|mary
```

Comment: Thanks for all your guys help. Sorry not to mention the langauge. I do think the language should be .NET as I am using regular expression under "Nintex Workflow" which is built on SharePoint.